# How can I pass to a method an argument that could be a function of any type?

Tags: c++

I have to make a library as an assignment that would implement a menu-like functionality on a linux terminal. So I have to for each submenu enable a position to be either another submenu or a call to some function.

I was wondering how to implement such a call. Since it is to be a library, it could be used to a dozen of different kinds of functions, taking different number and types of arguments.

How to implement such a method calling another functions that would not assume anything about those functions any yet could call them? Should I use templates somehow or is there another method for that; or maybe I should implement it in a whole other way?

Comment: In C++, you can't really do this.

Comment: Why could it be any type of function? If they attach, say, an `bool(int, std::string)` to a menu item, and you click that menu item, how do the `int` and `std::string` get passed and where do they come from? And what do you do with the returned `bool`? Usually, your library specifies exactly what kind of function-like thing should be attached to a menu item.

Comment: @H2CO3 thank you. how are then such menus implemented?

Comment: These are called "Callback" routines. Most callback routines return a `void *` and accept a `void*` as an argument... or have a common signature..

Comment: In C++03 one would rather use Boost.Signal in combination with Boost.Bind or `std::vector<std::function<void()>` (with `std::bind`) in C++11.

Comment: @sftrabbit it is true that returning value is of no use. but if I would have, say, menu entry "write to file", then given file is to be defined globally, right? and in that way would menu callers have such objects passed?

Comment: Or you could do it the OO way and use the [command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use objects with virtual methods to do this. Then the application can decide, which parameters to put into the callback object.

```
class MenuItem;

// Callback Interface
struct MenuCallback
{
    virtual void activated(MenuItem* sender) = 0;
    virtual ~MenuCallback(){}
};

// Application Code
struct ConcretMenuCallback: MenuCallback
{
    ConcretMenuCallback(int parameter1);

    void activated(MenuItem* sender)
    {
        // do something with the data stored in this object
    }
};

// Example Item
class MenuItem
{
    MenuItem(MenuItem*parent, std::string caption, MenuCallback* cb);
    void notify();
}

MenuItem::notify()
{
    // call the callback-Object
    if(m_callback)
        m_callback->activated(this);
}
```